# Removing all directories excluding specific file types from linux terminal

Tags: linux, rm, delete

I have 1000s of directories with non-ordered names, each directory contains multiple files.

I would like to delete all the files in all directories, with the exception of files with .mrc extention.

I have been using rm -v !(*.mrc) to delete files from inside one directory (one at a time), but is there a ways to perform this process on all directories simultaneously.

Best,
J

Answer (score 1):

Enable `globstar` and use `**` pattern:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ rm -v **/!(*.mrc)
```